# If $G$ is nilpotent, then $N(G)>H$ for every $H<G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is the proof given:

Let $G=G_0 \unlhd G_1 \unlhd ... \unlhd G_n = 1$ be a central series. Then $[G_{i+1}, G]\leq G_i$.

Let $H<G$ be a proper subgroup, then $G_k\leq H$ and $G_{k-1} \nleq H$ for some $k$, hence $[G_{k-1}, G]\leq G_k \leq H$.

Hence $G_{k-1}$ normalizes $H$, so $N_G(H)>H$.

Why is it the case that $G_{k-1} = \{g\in G | H^g = H\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the case in general that $G_{k-1} = \{ g \in G : H^g = H \}$. The proof uses the following fact instead:

> If $[G_{k-1}, G] \leq H$, then $G_{k-1} \leq \{ g \in G : H^g = H \}$.

Proving this fact takes about one or two lines and uses nothing but the definitions.

Comment: Let $x\in C_{k-1}$, $y\in G$. Then $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\in H$, hence $xyH=yxH$. I'm still not getting anywhere.

Comment: I'd like to show that $x^{-1}Hx=H$.

Comment: Your goal is to show that $y^{-1}xy \in H$ for all $y \in G_{k-1}$ and $x \in H$. Well, we are assuming $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy \in H$, so ..?

Comment: Ah I see. I need to choose $y\in H$.